# How do I configure CsvHelper to always quote a specific field in its CSV output?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, fluent, csvhelper

I am using the [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) package to write my C# models to Csv. I am using fluent class maps (inheriting from CsvClassMap) to define my field to property mappings.

The issue I have is that some of the property values look like dates to excel. For example "2 - 4". I expect the end user to use excel to view these CSV's. I do not want these values to show as dates, so I am looking to have CsvHelper surround this field by quotes. However, I want ONLY this field surrounded by quotes. There are OTHER fields containing data I WANT to be interpreted (e.g. dates). Can I configure my mapping to specify this field should be quoted? I've played with using a type converter, but that's clearly the wrong approach because this is converting the VALUE and not instructing how to format the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 12 you can do this:

```
const int indexToQuote = 4;
csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => 
    context.Record.Count == indexToQuote && 
    context.HasHeaderBeenWritten;
```

Comment: I accepted because it is a better end result, but it's still not great. Ideally, any solution would be declarative, not imperative. Too old for me to invest in solving now ;-)

Comment: Agreed, it is a mediocre solution.  Thanks for accepting through, glad you're not the type to shoot the messenger :)

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently quoting is not what I needed to do. Excel quite helpfully decides to treat numeric values that look remotely like dates as dates, unless the field begins with a space (which it then will not display). I feel like relying on this is rather hackish, but I'll take it. FWIW, here's the type converter I used:

```
public class LeadingSpaceTypeConverter : DefaultTypeConverter {

    public override string ConvertToString( TypeConverterOptions options, object value ) {
        if (value == null ) {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        return String.Concat(" ", value.ToString());
    }
}
```

And the fluent code:

```
Map( m => m.CompanySize ).TypeConverter<LeadingSpaceTypeConverter>().Index( 4 );
```